# Selectors not working on ajax response

Tags: ajax, materialize

I'm using ajax to submit pages and return content blocks based on user action for an onboarding sequence.

If have a page which loads and get 1 content element, the user then clicks Yes or No, which loads the next content element into the same space (via ajax).

For some reason my selectors don't seem to be working on that ajax loaded html.

Here is my ajax function which gets the form:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loader").toggleClass('progress');
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    url: baseUrl+'welcome/user_confirmation_form',
    complete: function( response ) {
    $("#loader").toggleClass('progress');
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
        $("div.welcome-page > .col").html(response.response);

        },
    error: function( response ) {
        $("#next-steps").html(response.response);
    }
    });
```

I'm then trying to access the submit button (have tried doing it as a ahref and button type=submit but nothing seems to be selecting the event.

```
$('div.welcome-page').on('submit', "user_complete", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('FOund form');

            var user = $(this).serializeArray();
            console.log(user);
        });
```

If I view source, the ajax returned HTML is not even in the dom, but it is when viewing the UI normally.

I'm guessing this has something to do with it?

How can I select all the form data?

Any time I click on the button or ahref it just fires the same page again.

Comment: When do you try to manipulate the form? AJAX is loaded asynchronous. The handler is called, when all current script has run and control is given back to browser. Are you sure to access *after* DOM insertion?

Answer (score 1):

If user_complete is a class you are assigning on your submit button in your loaded html, then you are missing a .

```
$('div.welcome-page').on('submit', ".user_complete", function(e) {
```

But this will only work if you're using a submit action as this is listening for a submit event. Maybe you want to listen for a click event?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the events to your handlers for your newly added HTML elements. Your original call to

```
$('div.welcome-page').on('submit' ...
```

Only bound the event handler for the elements that were on the page at that point in time.

You can put your handler into a function ...

```
var myHandler = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var user = $(this).serializeArray();
}
```

And then after you load the new HTML you need to bind the handler to the event. So, on success with the AJAX you would ...

```
success: function( response ) {
  $("div.welcome-page > .col").html(response.response);
  $('div.welcome-page').on('submit', "user_complete", myHandler);
},
```